# Java 8 timezone conversion

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, java-time, datetime-conversion

I know there are similar questions like this, but I wasn't quite able to find the example similar to mine. I learned about `LocalDateTime` and `ZonedDateTime` but I don't know how to tell my `ZonedDateTime` what's assumed timezone of parsed date.

I'm migrating from Java 7 to Java 8. In my code, I have a method like this:

```
public String changeTZ(String tzFrom, String tzTo, String dateToChange) {
    ZoneId zoneFrom = ZoneId.of(tzFrom);
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateFormat.toPattern());
    LocalDateTime localtDateAndTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateToChange, formatter);
    ZonedDateTime dateAndTimeINeed = ZonedDateTime.of(localtDateAndTime, zoneFrom );

    ZonedDateTime rezDate = dateAndTimeINeed.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of(tzTo));

    return formatter.format(rezDate);
}
```

Example usage is:

```
String rez = changeTZ("CEST", "UTC", "2017-08-10 14:23:58");
```

As you can see it receives datetime in form of string, timezone date is in `tzFrom` variable and TZ I need (`toTo` variable).

Code which does that in Java 7 is absurd and complex so I won't enlist it here. Can you please tell me how to achieve the same in Java 8 without changing method interface (arguments and return type)? What about DST? Is it handled automatically in Java 8?

Note that method also supports timezones in form of "CEST", "CET", "UTC" as well as standard ones like "Europe/London".

Comment: see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25946133/180100

Comment: Java 8 uses [IANA timezones names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (always in the format `Region/City`, like `America/Sao_Paulo` or `Europe/Berlin`).
It doesn't **directly** support 3-letter abbreviations (like `CST` or `PST`) because they are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18407231/7605325), although you can use some [arbitrary defaults](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#SHORT_IDS) for them.

Comment: @Robin i edited my question.

Comment: *"and seems ok"* - are you sure that `ZoneId.of("CEST")` doesn't throw an exception? For me it does.

Comment: @Hugo it does. But if i use CET, it will observer DST and automatically give me CEST time if needed (at least, that's what i got from tests)

Comment: *"What about DST?"* - `ZoneId` and  `ZonedDateTime` classes automatically handle DST effects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java 8 uses [IANA timezones names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (always in the format `Region/City`, like `America/Sao_Paulo` or `Europe/Berlin`).
Avoid using the short abbreviations (like `CEST` or `PST`) because they are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18407231/7605325).

Actually, those names don't work with `ZoneId` mainly because of this ambiguity (CST, for example, can be "Central Standard Time", "Cuba Standard Time" or "China Standard Time"). *Actually, some of them might work due to retro-compatibility reasons, but it's not guaranteed to work with all of them.*

I'm assuming that CEST is the [Central European Summer Time](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/cest). There are lots of different countries (and timezones) that are currently in CEST, so the API can't decide which timezone to choose if you just pass "CEST" to it.

That's because a timezone contains all the different offsets a region had during its history. There may be lots of countries using CEST today, but their history differs in the past (some might had DST in different years, or used a different offset and then changed, etc), and that's why they have one timezone for each.

To use such short names (like `CEST`), though, you can define some defaults for each one (which will be an arbitrary choice) and put these choices in a map:

```
// map of custom zone names
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
// setting my arbitrary choices for each name
map.put("CEST", "Europe/Berlin"); // Berlin during DST period
map.put("CET", "Europe/Berlin"); // Berlin during non-DST period
// ... and so on
```

Then you can use this map to create the `ZoneId`:

```
// use the custom map to create the ZoneId
ZoneId zoneFrom = ZoneId.of(tzFrom, map);
...
// use the custom map to create the ZoneId
ZonedDateTime rezDate = dateAndTimeINeed.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of(tzTo, map));
```

I've chosen `Europe/Berlin`, but of course you can change it to whatever timezone you need. You can get a list of available timezones (and choose the one that fits best your system) by calling `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`.

---

Using the map above:

```
System.out.println(changeTZ("CEST", "UTC", "2017-08-10 14:23:58"));
```

This code outputs:

> 2017-08-10 12:23:58

Note that 14:23 in `CEST` (which I chose to be `Europe/Berlin`) is 12:23 in UTC, which is correct because in **August** Berlin is in DST (offset is `+02:00`).

`ZoneId` and `ZonedDateTime` classes handle DST effects automatically. You can check this by choosing a date in January (when DST is not in effect in Berlin):

```
// January is not DST, so use CET
System.out.println(changeTZ("CET", "UTC", "2017-01-10 14:23:58"));
```

The output is:

> 2017-01-10 13:23:58

In **January** Berlin is not in DST, so the offset is `+01:00`, then 14:23 in Berlin becomes 13:23 in UTC.

---

Of course the ideal is to always use the full names (like `Europe/Berlin`), but the custom map is an alternative if you don't have control over the inputs.

Java 8 also has a [built-in predefined map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#SHORT_IDS), but as any other predefined stuff, the choices are arbitrary and not necessarily the ones you need.

Comment: Probably in the original interface take in input CEST, CET etc... to map an offsets instead of zone. If it's true the best mapping he can do should be like `map.put("CEST", "+2");` and `map.put("CET", "+1");` etc...

Comment: @Phoenix That would be an option, but I prefer to use a timezone, because the offset is "less accurate" when it comes to historical information (when DST starts and ends). For this specific case it might work, but I think the ideal is to use a timezone.

Comment: I'll accept this answer because it really explains things in detail. Extra points for "CET" / "CEST" mapping :)

Comment: @guest86 Another detail: specifically for "UTC", you can use the constant `ZoneOffset.UTC` instead of `ZoneId.of` (although the final result is the same)

Answer (score 5):

This solution uses the IANA timezones names mentioned by Hugo in the comments to get the `ZoneId` (more details [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#of-java.lang.String-)). Will throw an exception if you use it with *CEST*.

```
public static String changeTZ(String tzFrom, String tzTo, String dateToChange){
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").withZone(ZoneId.of(tzFrom));
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateToChange, dtf);
    DateTimeFormatter dtf2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").withZone(ZoneId.of(tzTo));  
    return zdt.format(dtf2);
}
```

Use like:

```
String rez = changeTZ("US/Alaska", "Europe/Berlin", "2017-08-10 14:23:58");
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really nice and short

Answer (score 0):

Here is a class that does the job.

```
public class TimeZoneConverter {

    private static String datePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String sourceDate = "2017-02-27 16:00:00";
        String resultDate = convertTimeZone("EET", "UTC", sourceDate);

        System.out.println("EET: "+ sourceDate);
        System.out.println("UTC: "+ resultDate);
    }

    public static String convertTimeZone(String timeZoneFrom, String timeZoneTo, String date) throws ParseException {
        long timestamp = stringToTimestamp(date, timeZoneFrom);
        String result = timestampToString(timestamp, timeZoneTo);
        return result;
    }

    public static long stringToTimestamp(String time, String timeZone) throws ParseException {
        DateFormat format = getDateFormat(timeZone);
        return format.parse(time).getTime();
    }

    public static String timestampToString(long timestamp, String timeZone) {
        DateFormat format = getDateFormat(timeZone);
        return format.format(new Date(timestamp));
    }

    private static DateFormat getDateFormat(String timeZone) {
        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(datePattern);
        format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone));
        return format;
    }

}
```